# How to fix Xceed DateTimePicker ArgumentOutOfRangeException Error

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datetimepicker, xceed

I am using the Xceed DateTimePicker as the control in a wpf DataGrid for all columns that are bound to a Date property.  Each of the those columns is defined as follows:

```
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn
    Header="Charge Date"
    Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Path=ChargeDate, StringFormat=yyyy-MM-dd, Converter={StaticResource conDate}}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <tk:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding Path=ChargeDate}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I don't think it is pertinent to my question, but for completeness sake, here is the styling for the pickers:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DateTimePicker}">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="2017-01-01" />
    <Setter Property="DisplayDefaultValueOnEmptyText" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ShowButtonSpinner" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TimePickerVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="AutoCloseCalendar" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Format" Value="Custom" />
    <Setter Property="FormatString" Value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</Style>
```

This works for datagrid cells that are already populated or when I am entering data in a new row.  However when I click on an empty cell in an existing row, I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'SelectedDate value is not valid.'
```

Why is the error only when I am enter data in an existing row?  No code-behind is being executed when this exception happens so I don't know where to look for the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. To fix this set the ClipValueToMinMax property to "True". This will prevent the value from going below minimum/above maximum without throwing an exception.

```
<xceed:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding DateTime}"
                      Minimum="{Binding DateTimeMinimum}"
                      Maximum="{Binding DateTimeMaximum}"
                      ClipValueToMinMax="True"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have set the `Minimum` property to `2017-01-01`, you should also set the default value to the same date:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type tk:DateTimePicker}">
    <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Default" Value="2017-01-01" />
    <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="2017-01-01" />
    <Setter Property="DisplayDefaultValueOnEmptyText" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ShowButtonSpinner" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TimePickerVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="AutoCloseCalendar" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Format" Value="Custom" />
    <Setter Property="FormatString" Value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
</Style>
```

You will get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the default value or value is less than the minimum value and this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Excellent observation -  I added the default value to the Style.  However, I get the same exception!

Comment: What cell are you clicking in when you get the exception? Please provide a repo of your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK, let me put together a sample.

Comment: Update: I haven't forgotten this problem.  I've stripped the solution down to the bare essentials, such as removing all the calls to the database, and in doing so I'm getting a lot of binding errors that I haven't traced down yet.  But I'm still working on it.  Maybe when I figure that out, I'll uncover the problem listed here.