# Extended datetimepicker raise error DateRange because DateTime Device not in range

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker, xceed

Error appear when click Datepicker box. Error as below:
[image]

XAML and CS Code:
[image]

[image]

Device DateTime Value is: 21-May-11

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `ClipValueToMinMax` to `true` to prevent the datetime to be out of the range specified by `Minimum` and `Maximum`.

```
dateEnd.ClipValueToMinMax = true;
```

Comment: I saw this answer before I post this question. Still I got error even I add ClipValueToMinMax.

Comment: Before I post this question I find your answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070932/how-to-fix-xceed-datetimepicker-argumentoutofrangeexception-error)

but still I got error even I set ClipValueToMinMax. That why I not vote your answer.